# How to follow user at Twitter?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-3, twitter

I want to follow a user on Twitter with the help of code. I am using below mentioned code.

```
HttpWebRequest messageRequest = 
(HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create("http://twitter.com/friendships/create/" + 
                                           userIdToFollow + ".xml?follow=true");
messageRequest.Method = "POST";
messageRequest.Credentials = new NetworkCredential(username, password);
messageRequest.ContentLength = 0;
messageRequest.ContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";
WebResponse response = messageRequest.GetResponse();
StreamReader sReader = new StreamReader(response.GetResponseStream());
responseStr = sReader.ReadToEnd();
```

I am getting an error while getting the response

> The remote server returned an error: (404) Not Found.

Am I missing something ?

Answer (score 1):

What version of the API are you using?

**v1**

https://dev.twitter.com/docs/api/1/post/friendships/create

**v1.1**

https://api.twitter.com/1.1/friendships/create.json

---

I'm not sure where you got that Url but did you try using **https**?

Comment: Can you show some sample code. It will be very useful. Thank You for the reply

Comment: hunter +1 for the help so far : Thanks for the help so far. Can you modify my code to make it work ?

Answer (score 1):

Yep. The correct URL:

```
https://api.twitter.com/1.1/friendships/create
```

See this resource: https://dev.twitter.com/docs/api/1.1/post/friendships/create

Comment: Should the code line be like this : `HttpWebRequest messageRequest = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create("https://api.twitter.com/1.1/friendships/create/" + UserToFollow + ".xml?follow=true");` ?

Comment: No, you pass the user id to follow as a query string param. Please read the documentation. It will answer all your questions.

Comment: Chris +1 : Thanks for the help so far. Can you please help how to pass userid as parameter in c# along with Url ?